# k means plot with the original data in r

Tags: r, plot, k-means

Currently I am exploring `kmeans` function. I have a simple text file (`test.txt`) with the following entries. The data can be split into 2 clusters.

```
    1 
    2
    3
    8
    9
   10
```

How to plot the results of `kmeans` function ( using `plot` function ) along with the original data? I am also interested in observing how the clusters are distributed along with their centroids?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31083/how-to-produce-a-pretty-plot-of-the-results-of-k-means-cluster-analysis

Comment: Thanks Mehdi! But I need a solution using the basic "plot" function.

Comment: Try `plot(test$V1, col = kmeans(test$V1, 2)$cluster)` (assuming your column is called `V1`)

Comment: Thanks David!....It worked and helped me!....But how to highlight the center of the cluster ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the example from `example(kmeans)`:

```
# This is just to generate example data
test <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(test) <- c("V1", "V2")

#store the kmeans in a variable called cl
(cl <- kmeans(test, 2))

# plot it and also plot the points of the centeroids
plot(test, col = cl$cluster)
points(cl$centers, col = 1:2, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

**Edit**

OP has some additional questions:

```
(cl <- kmeans(test, 2))
plot(test, col = cl$cluster)
points(cl$centers, col = 1:2, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

The above code results in:
[image: case1]

```
(cl <- kmeans(test[,1], 2))
plot(test[,1], col = cl$cluster)
points(cl$centers, col = 1:2, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

The above code results in:
[image: case2]

```
(cl <- kmeans(test[,1], 2))
plot(cbind(0,test[,1]),  col = cl$cluster)
points(cbind(0,cl$centers), col = 1:2, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

The above code results in:
[image: case3]

**explained**

In case 1 the data has two dimensions (V1, V2), so the centroids have two coordinates just as very point in the plot. In case 2 the data is one dimensional (V1) just like your data. R gives every point an index, and this results in x values being index values, the centroids also have only one coordinate thats why you see them all the way to the left of the plot.
case 3 is what one dimensional data actually looks like if you plot it only in one dimension.

**conclusion**

Your data is one dimensional, if you plot it in two dimensions you get something like case two where x values are given by R, which are index values. Plotting it like that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: But  can you show me the steps with my test.txt file!

Comment: Your data has only one dimension so you will end up with a weird plot. To do so you have to change the third and fourth occurrence of `test` to `test[,1]`

Comment: Thanks Mehdi ! But with the change I am not getting the center of the cluster. And how is `test[,1]`  different from test ?

Comment: @Soumajit I've made an edit to my answer to explain it and your situation